# React3Fiber und Fabric.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js, fabricjs, react-three-fiber

I want to use fabricjs as a canvasTexture in react3fiber. It does work, but it is not interactive.

Does anyone have solution to make the text editable?

I implemented Fabric.js successfully with a "canvasTexture" in react3fiber application. The canvas is mapped to plane geometry
Now i want to have access for pointer events on fabric canvas. Edit Text, move image, textures...

Thats my code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { fabric } from "fabric";

export default function Plane() {
  
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const textureRef = useRef() as any;
  const [fabricCanvas, setFabricCanvas] = useState<fabric.Canvas >(null!);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasEl.width = 1024;
    canvasEl.height = 1024;
    const fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl);
    setFabricCanvas(fCanvas);
    canvasRef.current = canvasEl;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fabricCanvas) { 
      fabricCanvas.on("after:render", () => {
        textureRef.current.needsUpdate = true;
      });
    }
  }, [fabricCanvas]);

  function addRect() {
    const textBox = new fabric.Textbox('Hello', {
      width: 250,
      top: 50,
      left: 50,
      textBackgroundColor: 'red',
      fontSize: 22,
      textAlign: 'left',
      padding: 2,
      editable: true
    });
    if (fabricCanvas) { 
      fabricCanvas.add(textBox);
      fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(textBox);
    }
  }

  return (
    <mesh
    onClick={addRect}
    >
      <planeGeometry args={[1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" metalness={0} roughness={1}>
        <canvasTexture
          ref={textureRef}
          attach="map"
          image={canvasRef.current}
        ></canvasTexture>
      </meshStandardMaterial>
    </mesh>
  );
}
```